# Percentage Increase and Dates

Tags: statistics, arithmetic, economics, percentages

Suppose we have the following data:

```
               begin date     end date   quantity
                 10/01/13      01/06/14      5
                 01/07/14      01/01/2015    7.5
                 01/02/2015    07/03/2015    10.67
```

The average difference between end dates is about 0.5 years. I want to project the future quantities using the average difference between end dates. I have something like the following:

```
                  begin date     end date   quantity
                 10/01/13      01/06/14      5
                 01/07/14      01/01/2015    7.5
                 01/02/2015    07/03/2015    10.67
                 07/04/2015    01/02/2016 
                 01/03/2016    07/03/2016       
                 07/04/2016    01/02/2017 
                 01/03/2017    07/04/2017
```

The end dates were determined by adding 0.745 years (~182 days) to the start dates. Is there any good way of getting the four future projections for quantity?

Could I look at the percentage increase in quantity based on end dates:

$$ \frac{\frac{7.5-5}{5}}{\text{time between 01/06/14 and 01/01/2015}}$$
$$                                 \vdots $$

and somehow apply that?

Comment: $3$-point moving averages? So first forecast would be $(5+7.5+10.67)/3=7.72$. The fifth value would be $(7.5+10.67+7.72)/3=8.63$ and so on...

Comment: @Autolatry: But that does not take into account the time intervals.

Comment: That's true but I have a query about that, you write that $0.745$ years is $\simeq 182$ days, but I would say $182$ days is $\simeq 0.5$ years?

Comment: @Autolatry: I have edited my question. I mean the average difference was 0.5 years.

Comment: Does the quantity increases about $2.5(=7.5-5.0)$ between 01/07/14  and 01/01/2015 ?